How to update JSF value from change in bean value
I have two similar issues with the same goal. In one case I change a dropdown value and need to select/unselect a checkbox. Like this:
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{AdhocReportBean.adhocSearchType}" 
    valueChangeListener="#{AdhocReportBean.changeAdhocSearchType}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{AdhocReportBean.adhocSearchTypeOptions}" />
    <f:ajax render="@all" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
.... more stuff in here....
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{AdhocReportBean.showdetails}" id="cb"/>

And later on there is a search button. In this case, I want to change the showdetails value based upon the adhocSearchType value that I just changed. I can have my valueChangeListener method change the showdetails value, but when I click search, the showdetails is submitted from the form, essentially ignoring my change in the bean.
A similar/related question is can I somehow have that checkbox be in 2 places on the page? So that I can update the showdetails value from multiple places. If I just put in on the page twice, the last one on the page wins.
I can even do a javascript hack if needed, but the ID of the checkbox will not remain "cb" so not sure how to have the javascript get the component to change the value.
I see you can do this with Primefaces, but we have plain JSF. Is there a way to "push" changes somehow from the bean to the page values?
Thank you for any ideas!
